# React native: Resume app from background on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm writing VoIP application, and mine VoIP service fire JS event when incoming call received.

And if Application is in background (e.g. hidden), I need to show Application to display answer/decline buttons.

I tried to start new Intent and Application is shown, but JS state is missed.

Is it possible resume application without loosing JS state ?

Comment: Can you add more information? In my understanding if you do nothing while pause/resume, the state will remains while resumed

Comment: I wrote Android Service that working in background, that service fire event when somebody calls through SIP. This event also received in JS thread (through react bridge), and I can perform some actions. But I don't know how to resume application when it's in background. (e.g. AppState.currentState is background)

Answer (score 0):

I'm building the same thing at the minute and the best way for this use case is using GCM to wake up the phone in either [Doze mode or App Standby mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html). That is, you don't have to maintain a persistent connection between your app and your VoIP server.

However, since react-native provides only push notification for iOS, you have to use a [third-party module](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can try running a service to handle it.
Here is more detail from Android Developer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html